# How to use sequential relations

Tags: activerecord, yii

In my application, I have 3 tables: `state`, `city`, `district`, Each state has many cities in it, and each city contains many districts. I already defined those relations in `state` and `city` models.

Now I need to retrieve a list of all `state`, `city`, and `district` in to a multidimensional array that reflexes those relations. An example will look like this:

```
[
    'A state' => [
        ['AA city' => ['AA1 district', 'AA2 district']],
        ['AB city'] => ['AB1 district']
    ]
]
```

Is it possible to use `Model` that leverages relations that I define to get the job done effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can fetch the data with the relations like this:

```
$states = State::model()->with('cities.districts')->findAll();
```

Where `State` should be you state model name. `cities` is the name of the relation as defined in the relations array in `State`. And `districts` is the name of the relation as defined in the relations array in `City`.

You can loop through the states and access the de cities and districts with a simple `->`

```
foreach($states as $state) {
    var_dump($state->cities); // will probably be an array of cities

    foreach($state->cities as $city) {
        var_dump($city->districts); // will probably be an array of districts
    }
}
```